# How to populate two text fields from one select drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML produced by CakePHP's form helper. In the interface, the user is selecting two dates which are then used in the resulting PHP to pull data from MySQL. I have also provided the user with "financial months", which are defined in MySQL as a shortcut to pre-populate the two date fields. However, I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this as my jQuery/Javascript knowledge is very limited.

What I want to do:
When user selects something from the SELECT box, the value of the option before the _ is pulled in to date1, and the value of the option after the _ is pulled in to date 2.

Is this possible?

edit:
Here is the code in CakePHP that produces the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/revenuelines.js"></script>

<h1>Lock revenue</h1>

<div class="inner">

    <p>Select two dates to lock revenue for the specified period.</p>

    <?php

    echo $this->Form->create('lock');

    ?>

    <span>Between</span>
    <?php

    echo $this->Form->input('RevenueLine.date1', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'input datepicker', 'label' => false));

    echo "&nbsp;and&nbsp;";

    echo $this->Form->input('RevenueLine.date2', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'input datepicker', 'label' => false));

    echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'submit_black gradient', 'style' => 'display: inline;')); 

    echo $this->Form->input('FinancialMonth.selector', array('label' => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...or select financial month to auto-populate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', 'div' => false, 'class' => 'input', 'options' => $months));

    echo $this->Form->end(); 

    ?>
</div>
```

Here is the actual HTML produced:

```
<div id="content">

                        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/revenuelines.js"></script>

<h1>Lock revenue</h1>

<div class="inner">

    <p>Select two dates to lock revenue for the specified period.</p>

    <form action="/revenue_lines/lock" id="lockLockForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>
    <span>Between</span>
    <input name="data[RevenueLine][date1]" class="input datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text" id="RevenueLineDate1">&nbsp;and&nbsp;<input name="data[RevenueLine][date2]" class="input datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text" id="RevenueLineDate2"><input class="submit_black gradient" style="display: inline;" type="submit" value="Submit"><label for="FinancialMonthSelector">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...or select financial month to auto-populate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><select name="data[FinancialMonth][selector]" class="input" id="FinancialMonthSelector">
<option value="22JUN2013_26JUL2013">2013 - July</option>
<option value="27JUL2013_30AUG2013">2013 - August</option>
</select></form></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Fixed HTML display. Note I am using the chosen select jQuery plug-in - I have deleted the irrelevant extra HTML from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is!, code here:

jQuery **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/HayMR/3/)** and code under:

```
$('#FinancialMonthSelector').on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value; // get the value from this select
    var parts = val.split("_"); // split the value on the "_" generating an array
    $('#RevenueLineDate1').val(parts[0]); // give input LineDate1 the arrays first value
    $('#RevenueLineDate2').val(parts[1]); // give input LineDate2 the arrays second value
});
```

**and** in plain javascript ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HayMR/4/))

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById('FinancialMonthSelector');
selectEl.onchange = function () {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('RevenueLineDate1');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('RevenueLineDate2');
    var val = this.value;
    var parts = val.split("_");
    input1.value = parts[0];
    input2.value = parts[1];
}
```

Comment: This works on JS Fiddle and even when on JS Fiddle using the code I have pasted into my system.
http://jsfiddle.net/sez9b/
However, it doesn't work in my actual system! Any ideas?

Comment: @gazareth, do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: @gazareth, I updated with a plain javascript version also. Just in case.

Comment: Yep, jQuery is loaded - the datetimepicker of jQuery UI works fine.

Comment: @gazareth, is the select loaded with page or after/dynamically?

Comment: It's loaded with the page.

Comment: I added the CakePHP view that produces the form above

Comment: @gazareth, what is revenuelines.js? Btw, did you try the javascript version, sometimes jQuery is not compatible and javascript is a better solution. One more thing I corrected the code because I used "value" and that is a keyword, shouldn't be used.

Comment: revenuelines.js is a file containing the jquery code. I have other jQuery elements working on the same page so I shouldn't need the JS version (that didn't work either, anyway).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the jQuery code. If I paste it into the Chrome Dev Tools console it then works perfectly. So it is not loading the function on page load?

Comment: The problem was my misunderstanding of jQuery. When i put the code inside the existing document ready function in "functions.js", it worked ok :-)

Comment: @gazareth, don't put it inside other script files, it's not good if in the future your remove that file. Use `$(document).ready(function(){` code here `});` on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the change event, and then just split on `_` (no error checking done here you can do that yourself)

```
$("#FinancialMonthSelector").change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  var dates = value.split("_");
  $("#RevenueLineDate1").val( dates[0] );
  $("#RevenueLineDate2").val( dates[1] );
});
```